# replacing pi with 3.14 in a String recursively (no loops)

Tags: java

Given a string, compute recursively (no loops) a new string where all appearances of "pi" have been replaced by "3.14".

```
changePi("xpix") → "x3.14x"
changePi("pipi") → "3.143.14"
changePi("pip") → "3.14p"
```

My code worked perfectly but is there any other way (only recursively no loops) to do this problem without having to create a new string str2 ?
Thank you in advance
here is my code :

```
    public  String changePi(String str) {
    String str2 = "";
    return changePi(str, str2);
}

public String changePi(String str, String str2) {
    if (str.length() == 0)
        return str2;

    else {
        if (str.endsWith("pi")) {
            str2 = 3.14 + str2;
            return changePi(str.substring(0, str.length() - 2), str2);
        } else
            str2 = str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + str2;

    }
    return changePi(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), str2);

}
```

Comment: a. I would put the last return line in the else clause (as all other flows are "returned", leaving it outside creates less readable code)
b. What you're asking is if there's an "in-place" solution? since clearly you need at least a string of length of str, sadly it seems unlikely as "3.14" is longer than "pi", what I would recommend, though, to improve performance, is to use a StringBuilder (so that you can swap out the various + operations with stringBuilder.append and finally return stringbuilder.toString())

Answer (score 1):

Using the same mechanism you can use a `StringBuilder` and modify it in-situ. This should be much more memory efficient.

```
private static final String PI = "pi";
private static final String THREE_POINT_ONE_FOUR = "3.14";

public String changePi(String s) {
    // Work with a StringBuilder for efficiency.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    // Start replacement at 0.
    return changePi(sb, 0).toString();
}

private StringBuilder changePi(StringBuilder sb, int i) {
    // Long enough?
    if (i + PI.length() <= sb.length()) {
        // Is it there?
        if (sb.subSequence(i, i + PI.length()).equals(PI)) {
            // Yes! - Replace it and recurse.
            sb.replace(i, i + PI.length(), THREE_POINT_ONE_FOUR);
            return changePi(sb, i + THREE_POINT_ONE_FOUR.length());
        } else {
            // Not there - step to next.
            return changePi(sb, i + 1);
        }
    }
    return sb;
}

private void test(String s) {
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + changePi(s));
}

private void test() {
    test("pipi");
    test("xpix");
    test("pip");
}
```

Comment: Passing a string to a recirssive function is not recommended nor efficient.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb I am using a `StringBuilder` here!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the same mistake as you did in your previous question. Also I would prefer to check if a string starts with, and not ends with a string...I am assuming that you would like something that you can understand and it's easy to explain.

> 1. Can you match "pi" or the string is already less than *length("pi")* symbols -> cant do nothing much so return it.
> 2. Does it starts with "pi"? If so return the replacement concatenated with the rest of the string (just the rest starts *length("pi")* characters away from the 0th index...
> 3. If it isn't starting with "pi" than concatenate the first character with what's the output of *changePi* and the rest of the string as its input.

```
public static String changePi(String str) {
    if (str.length() < "pi".length()) {
        return str;
    }

    if (str.startsWith("pi")) {
        return "3.14" + changePi(str.substring("pi".length(), str.length()));
    }

    return str.charAt(0) + changePi(str.substring(1, str.length()));
}
```

And still if you like to use the "endsWith" logic then here is the same algorythm applied.

```
public static String changePi(String str) {
    if (str.length() < "pi".length()) {
        return str;
    }

    if (str.endsWith("pi")) {
        return changePi(str.substring(0, str.length() - "pi".length())) + "3.14";
    }

    return changePi(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)) + str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: You are calling substring per recurssive call, this O(n^2), there is a simpler O(n) solution, also passing a string as an argument to a recurssive function is not efficient.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb this answer isn't aiming to give the optimal recursive solution for the problem, nor the best approach for it. It aims to bring some more light to OP so he can improve his own style. I could easily implement an approach which is O(n) but this won't be an improvement of the OP's solution, but one of my own...

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a nice approach (it's a little confusing as you replace twice, I believe) and I would make sth like:

- If `str` <= than `2`, check `str` if equals `pi`, return `3,14` or `str`
- Else, if ends with `pi` return `Change(str-2)+Change(last2)`, else return `Change(str-1)+Change(lastChar)`

Edited: now changes `pi` for `3,14`

Comment: I think the person wants to replace pi with 3.14, not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static  String changePi(String str) {
int num = str.indexOf("pi");
if (num==-1) return str;
return str.substring(0,num)+"3.14"+changePi(str.substring(num+2));

}
```

does it, though I guess it depends what you mean by create a new string. In a sense this does, but without naming it.

Answer (score 0):

Voila! simple and clean:

```
String fun(int i) {
        if(i == s.length()) return "";
        if(i+1 < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == 'p' && s.charAt(i+1) == 'i') {
            return "3.14" + fun(i+2);
        } else {
            return s.charAt(i) + fun(i+1);
        }
}
```

Comment: You didn't pass s, if p is the last letter i'm guessing you'll try accessing illegal index of s, and memory wise this isn't better than the original solution
edit: I see you've added a check to avoid illegal index access

Comment: String are immutable in java there is now way to change the original, maybe using string builder but the question author didn't specify that.

Comment: Since strings are immutable the easy answer is: no, can't return the result without creating a string.
Besides, using + and non-final strings ("3.14") means you'll be creating more string than you have to which, for most inputs, is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've never written Java before, but this seems to work:

```
public class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(changePi("xpix"));
  System.out.println(changePi("pipi"));
  System.out.println(changePi("pip"));
 }

 public static String changePi(String str) {
  int len = str.length();
  if (len < 2)
   return str;

  if (str.endsWith("pi"))
   return changePi(str.substring(0, len - 2)) + "3.14";
  else
   return changePi(str.substring(0, len - 1)) + str.substring(len - 1, len);
 }
}
```

**Explaination:**

This is closer to a true recursive solution, since the function doesn't know about the right portion of the string (no `str2`), it's the calling function's responsibility to keep track of it.

The terminal case is running on a string shorter than `"pi"`, in which case we return the remainder (0 or 1 chars).

If the string ends in `"pi"`, we take the rest of the string before that and pass that to the new iteration, but keep in  mind to append "3.14" when that returns.

If the string doesn't end in  that, we just break off a single character and keep it to reattach.

**Criticism:**

This is horribly inefficient, though, as every `.substr` call is creating a whole new string object, and we do a lot of these calls.
You would have better luck using something like a linked list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you have not considered using regular expressions?

The following seems to work fine for all the test cases you mentioned:

```
public String changePi(String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("pi", "3.14");
}
```

Note that in Java a `String` is **immutable**. You cannot modify a `String` once you initialise it. Each time you are doing `str2 = ...` you are really creating a completely new `String` object.

If you need to do it recursively (i.e. it is some coursework), then what you did is perfectly fine (although  I would have used `indexOf("pi")` rather than `endsWith("pi")` and removing the trailing characters, but anyway.

It is the standard way to perform recursion, with `str2` being the accumulator (maybe you want to rename it so that it is clear what it is doing). You might want to consider using `StringBuilder` instead of a `String` for the second parameter, and in your base case you call `toString()` to get the final string... although honestly the difference in computation cost between creating a new `String` and using a `StringBuilder` has become very low.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String changePi(String str) {
  if(str.length() == 0){
    return str;
  }
  if(str.startsWith("pi")){
    return "3.14" + changePi(str.substring(2));
  }

  return str.substring(0,1) + changePi(str.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ChangePi {
    public static String changePi(String str) {
        String pi = "3.14";
        if (str.length() < 2) {
            return str;
        }
            return (str.substring(0, 2).equals("pi")) ? pi + changePi(str.substring(2)) :
                    str.substring(0, 1) + changePi(str.substring(1));
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer explains everything :)

```
public String changePi(String str) {
  if (str.length() < 1) return ""; // return if string length is zero
  String count = str.substring(0,1); // get the string
  int increment = 1; // increment variable to iterate the string
  if (str.length() > 1 && str.substring(0, 2).equals("pi")){
    //string length > 1 and it pi if found
    count = "3.14";
    increment = 2;//increment by 2 characters
  }
  //attach the 3.14 part or substring(0,1) and move forward in the string
  return count + changePi(str.substring(increment));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
public String changePi(String str) {
     if(str.equals("")){
       return str;
     }
     else if(str.length()>=2 && str.charAt(0)=='p' && str.charAt(1)=='i') {
       return "3.14" + changePi(str.substring(2));
     }
     else{
       return str.charAt(0) + changePi(str.substring(1));
     }
     
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String changePi(String str) {
  if(str.length() == 0) return str;
  if(str.charAt(0) == 'p' && str.length() >= 2){
    if(str.charAt(1) == 'i'){
      return "3.14" + changePi(str.substring(2));
    }
  }
    return str.charAt(0) + changePi(str.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the other answers this 2-year-old question already has, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.